# [: too many arguments with Binary Conditional Operators

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, operators

I am trying to write a script but it is giving the above error

```
 if [ [ [ "$1" != "abc" ] && [ "$1" != "def" ] ] || [ [ "$2" != "1" ] && [ "$2" != "0" ] ] ];
 then
    echo "Hello World"
 fi
```

Comment: You should use more meaningful variable's name as it will be hard for you (or other) to understand your code. For instance, at the beginning of you string do: `fish=$1; shark=$2`

Comment: As @anubhava answer suggest Bash syntax is more powerful than POSIX shell. However it is less portable.

Comment: `[` is not a grouping operator; it's a command name, and as such you cannot nest them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with `&&` and `||`. You can simplify it to this in BASH:

```
if [[ "$1" != "abc" && "$1" != "def" ]] || [[ "$2" != "1" && "$2" != "0" ]];
then
    echo "Hello World"
fi
```

Comment: Or even  `[[ ("$1" != "abc" && "$1" != "def" ) || ( "$2" != "1" && "$2" != "0" ) ]]`, which is equivalent to `[[ "$1" != "abc" && "$1" != "def" || "$2" != "1" && "$2" != "0" ]]`.

Comment: Yes sure `[[ ( "$1" != "abc" && "$1" != "def" ) || ( "$2" != "1" && "$2" != "0" ) ]]` should also work.